# How to Position my WPF Window exactly on top of Notepad?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to show a WPF form as pop up over a Notepad and the Pop window has to be at the same position and size of the Notepad. I am trying the below code and the code works fine if my Screen Resolution Scale is 100%. 
If it is not equal to 100%, I am not getting the exact position, the window misaligns.

I have tried the below code, it works just fine if my screen resolution scale is 100%

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }

About about = new About();
RECT r = new RECT();

Process [] notepads=Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        if(notepads.Length==0)return;            
        if (notepads[0] != null)
        {
IntPtr child= FindWindowEx(notepads[0].MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);

 if (GetWindowRect(child, ref r))
 {
    about.Top = r.Top;
   about.Left = r.Left;
 }
}

 about.ShowDialog();
```